# Placing the adverb "today" in a sentence

Tags: adverb-position

I'm not sure about where I should put the adverb "today" in the following sentence:

> His work is regarded as one of the highest peaks of Western culture.

I have a couple of options and I think that, even though with different emphases, all of them have the same meaning.

1. **Today**, his work is regarded as one of the highest peaks of Western culture.
2. His work is, **today**, regarded as one of the highest peaks of
   Western culture.
3. His work is regarded **today** as one of the highest peaks of
   Western culture.
4. His work is **today** regarded as one of the highest peaks of
   Western culture.

The first two options are like cheating, I'm sure they are correct. The third one sounds good to me. I'm not sure about the last one but I feel that it's like an incorrect version of the second one.

Is the fourth one OK? Any other option for placing the adverb?

Comment: It seems ok for me but the meanings are slightly different depending on where you place *today*, you emphasize it. -> *Today it's true but it wasn't before*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth one is absolutely fine. As for other options, you could also use;

5. His work is regarded as one of the highest peaks of Western culture **today**.

Although this one is clunky and kind of implies a literal interpretation of "today" more than the other sentences. Personally I prefer option three the most.

Comment: Don't think so. Putting *today* at the end makes the work regarded as the highest peak of modern Western culture. Putting *today* at the beginning makes the work currently regarded as the summit of all Western culture.